# Runtime error: pointer index expression with base 0x000000000000 overflowed to 0xffffffffffffffff for frequency sort

Tags: c++, algorithm

The question is to sort the letters of a given string in the decreasing order of their frequencies.

Eg: If string = "tree" output = "eert" or "eetr"
I used an unordered_map and counted the frequencies of each letter and added it to the resultant string in the decreasing order of frequencies.

This is what I have tried:

```
string frequencySort(string s1) {
    unordered_map<char,int> temp;
    for(char& c: s1)
        temp[c]++;
    string s = "";
    while(!temp.empty()) {
        int max = 0;
        char c='a';
        for(auto it:temp) {
            if(it.second > max) {
                c = it.first;
                max = it.second;
            }
        }
        for(int j=0;j<max;j++)
            s = s + c;
        temp.erase(temp.find(c));
    }
    return s;
}
```

My code is not working for large inputs. And changing int to long long does not make it work. So the maximum frequency is within INT_MAX. I get this error:

```
Runtime error: pointer index expression with base 0x000000000000 overflowed to 0xffffffffffffffff
```

I cannot paste the particular test case here as it exceeds the permissible body size for a question.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If the input exceeds the max limits, try splitting it and combining the results at the end

Comment: How large is the input your code is failing on?

Comment: Around 4000 characters

Comment: What is "extraordinary large" ???

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès IMHO, 4000 characters are not. ;-)

Comment: @3.14159 Are you sure the problem is with this code? Not the context of it?

Comment: OT.: You pass a `std::string` with "extraordinary large" data by value but access a `char` by reference (in `for(char& c: s1)`? Seems inconsistent to me...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I don't understand. "Context of it"? You're saying there's a problem with the logic?

Comment: "Context of it" -> where it is called. Couldn't you make it a [mcve] which can be compiled and run in an online compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing logically wrong in the code, but there are many inefficiencies that could make you run out of memory in a low-memory machine.

First you pass string by value:

> ```
> string frequencySort(string s1) {
> ```

This makes a new copy of the string each call, wasting twice as much memory than necessary.

Instead, prefer:

```
string frequencySort(const string & s1) {
```

The repeated reallocation required for the string can cause fragmentation in the memory manager, and cause more rapid out-of-memory issues:

> ```
>     for(int j=0;j<max;j++)
>         s = s + c;
> ```

To minimize reallocation issues, use `reserve`

```
string s = "";
s.reserve(s1.length());
```

And the biggest performance issue:

> ```
>         s = s + c;
> ```

The above code copies the same string again and again. Running in O(N<sup>2</sup>) and wrecking havoc on the heap with massive fragmentation.

There are also simple inefficiencies in the code that might have a big impact on runtime for large inputs, although they don't affect complexity. The use of `unordered_map` for such a small set (26 english letters) has a lot of time-overhead. It might be more efficient to use `std::map` in this case. For large inputs it is more efficient to hold an array

```
int map[256] = {0};
```

Unfortunately, for small inputs it might be slower. Also, this will not work so well for wide characters (where there are over 2<sup>16</sup> possible wide characters). But for ASCII this should work pretty well.

As a benchmark I ran the string that results from this command:

```
 perl -e 'print "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza" x 1000000; print "y\n"'
```

which generates a string of size 26 million characters.
The code with `int map[256]` completed in less than 4 seconds on my laptop.

Comment: I agree except for recommending `std::map` over `std::unordered_map` in this case. What kind of overhead are you implying in the latter (that the former does not have)? Both have separate allocations for each node, but `std::map` has to chase pointers 5 times (26 ~= 32 letters) or 8 times (256 characters) to descend the tree while `std::unordered_map` has to compute one hash + range reduction, index into a bucket array and then possibly iterate a few times depending on load factor (which you could mitigate by setting the load factor). I would argue pointer chasing takes longer here.

Comment: @MaxLanghof many people, including myself, have run benchmarks and found that below several thousands of items, gcc's map is faster than unordered_map. I don't know for the current setting though, and one must run the benchmarks.

Comment: @MaxLanghof it seems that unordered_map uses one big singly linked list over all its elements. This makes the buckets point to one element before the beginning of the bucket. This also has some cost

Comment: @MichaelVeksler I tried all of what you suggested and yet none of them worked at the time. Today I gave it another shot and the problem seems to have been at ```s=s+c``` in the final for loop. I changed it to ```s+=c``` and voila, it worked. I'm not sure how this assignment statement can cause a memory limit exceeded error.

Comment: @3.14159 the `s + c` has a memory cost, not only CPU. For once, it has to hold the original string while creating a new one. The old string is freed only after the `s =` part is executed. Also, this allocation/deallocation technique might interfere with the heap allocation algorithm - it **might** cause fragmentation. Which means, that the freed blocks are too small to be used in the next allocations. Your memory allocator might not be smart enough to merge smaller freed blocks. If that is the case, you'd run out of memory in that kind of code

Comment: @MichaelVeksler I understand. Thank you very much.