# I don't understand about memory issue of appending string

Tags: c++

[Runtime error: pointer index expression with base 0x000000000000 overflowed to 0xffffffffffffffff for frequency sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259287/runtime-error-pointer-index-expression-with-base-0x000000000000-overflowed-to-0)

In first answer of that link, it says that appending char to string can cause memory issue.

```cpp
string s = "";
char c = 'a';
int max = INT_MAX;
for(int j=0;j<max;j++)
    s = s + c;
```

The answer explains [`s=s+c` in above code copies the same string again and again so it will cause memory issue.] But I don't understand why that code copies the same string again and again.

Is there someone who is likely to make me understand that part :)?

Comment: How much RAM does you PC have? What is the value of INT_MAX? In a lot of languages strings are immutable, this means that each time you want to create a string out of two other string you have to acquire a new string to hold the result.

Comment: On each iteration of the loop, the string gets one character longer than before.  Also on each copy of the loop, a temporary string of length (j+1) is created, and then the data is copied (or in c++11, moved) from the temporary string back into `s`.

Comment: My ram has 8 GB. When I add climits header `#include <climits>`, I can use const value `INT_MAX`, which means the biggest value which int type can have in c++.

Comment: @HongGyuKim Can you provide a [mcve]? Because memory issues are largely platform dependent.

Comment: @HongGyuKim What in particular you don't undesrtand from the statement in the answer: _"The repeated reallocation required for the string can cause fragmentation in the memory manager, and cause more rapid out-of-memory issues"_ The string must be copied and thus memory needs to be allocated.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  Thanks!! It was helpful!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why that code copies the same string again and
>   again.

Okay, let's look at the what happens each time the loop is iterated:

```
s = s + c;
```

There are three things the program has to do in order to execute that line of code:

1. Compute the temporary value `s + c` -- to do that, the program has to create a temporary, anonymous `std::string` object, and allocate for it (from the heap) an internal byte-buffer that is at least one byte larger than the number of chars currently in `s` (so that it can hold all of `s`'s old contents, plus the additional char provided by `c`)
2. Set `s` equal to the temporary-string.  In C++03 and earlier, this would be done by reallocating `s`'s internal byte-buffer to be larger, then copying all of the bytes from the temporary-string into `s`'s new/larger buffer.  C++11 optimizes this a bit via the new move-assignment operator, so that all the bytes don't have to be copied; rather, `s` can simply take ownership of the temporary-string's byte-buffer.
3. Free the temporary string's resources, now that we're done using it.  In practice, this takes the form of the `std::string` class's destructor calling `delete[]` on the old (no-longer-large-enough) byte-buffer.

Given that the above is going to be performed at least 2 billion times in a loop, it's already quite inefficient.

However, what I think the answer you referred to was particularly concerned about was heap fragmentation.  Keep in mind that heap allocation doesn't work by magic; when you (or the `std::string` class, or anyone) asks to allocate N bytes of memory from the heap, the heap implementation's job is to find N bytes of *contiguous* memory and return it.  And since there is no provision in C++ for moving blocks of memory around (as doing so would invalidate any pointers that the program might have pointing into those blocks of memory), the heap can't create an N-byte contiguous-memory-chunk out of smaller chunks; instead, there has to be a range of contiguous-memory-space already available.  For example, it does the heap no good to have a total of 1GB of memory available, if that 1GB of memory is made up of thousands of nonconsecutive 1KB chunks and the caller is asking for a 2KB allocation.

Therefore, the heap's job is to efficiently allocate chunks of memory of the sizes the program requests, and when they are freed again, it will try to glue them back together into larger chunks again if it can, but it may not always be able to.  Certain patterns of allocating and freeing memory may result in *heap fragmentation*, which is simply a large number of discontinuous memory allocations that render the small regions of free memory between them unusable for large allocations.

Whether or not this particular allocate/free pattern would cause that, I'm not sure; given that only one or two buffers are being allocated at a time, the heap may be able to reabsorb them back into adjacent free-memory chunks as they get freed again -- it probably depends on the particular heap algorithm the system is using, as well as on whether any other threads are allocating/freeing heap memory while this is going on.  But I wouldn't be too surprised if there are systems out there where it would cause problems (particularly on 16-bit or 32-bit systems where virtual address space is limited, or embedded systems that don't use virtual memory)

Comment: Brilliant!! Your explanation is what I studied from school. But I didn't totally understand why heap fragmentation is so important. Sincerely Thanks for your careful comment!!